VM96:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'i', "import aws"... is not valid JSON
I am getting this error when I try to send an image directly to my S3 bucket in AWS. This is my frontend index.html and index.mjs:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="imageForm">
        <label for="imageInput">Choose an image:</label>
        <input id="imageInput" type="file" accept="image/*">
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

    <script type="module" src="index.mjs"></script>

</body>
</html>

index.mjs:.
const imageForm = document.querySelector("#imageForm")
const imageInput = document.querySelector("#imageInput")

imageForm.addEventListener("submit", async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const file = imageInput.files[0]

    // get secure url from our server
    const { url } = await fetch("../back/s3.mjs").then(res => res.json())
    console.log(url)
    // post the image directly to the s3 bucket

    // post request to my server to store any extra data
})

These are my backend files:

server.mjs:

import express from 'express'
import { generateUploadURL } from './s3.mjs'
const app = express()

app.use(express.static('front'))

app.get('/s3Url', async (req,res) => {
    const url = await generateUploadURL()
    res.send({ url })
})

app.listen(8080, () => console.log("listening on port 8080"))


s3.mjs:

import aws from 'aws-sdk'
import crypto from 'crypto'
import { promisify } from "util"
const randomBytes = promisify(crypto.randomBytes)



const region = "ap-south-1"
const bucketName = "direct-image-upload-to-s3-bucket"
const accessKeyId = "hidden"
const secretAccessKey = "hidden"

const s3 = new aws.S3({
    region,
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey,
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
})

export async function generateUploadURL() {
    const rawBytes = await randomBytes(16)
    const imageName = rawBytes.toString('hex')

    const params = ({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: imageName,
        Expires: 60
    })

    const uploadURL = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params)
    return uploadURL
}

i tried opening it on live server through vsc, the console read this error whenever i clicked submit: "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'i', "import aws"... is not valid JSON"
